# Get argument names of callable objects in the way they are called

Tags: python, function

I know that `inspect.getargspec` can be used to get the names of function arguments:

```
>>> from inspect import getargspec
>>> def foo1(a, b):
...     pass
...
>>> getargspec(foo1).args
['a', 'b']
```

But the following is not what I expected:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def foo2(self, a, b):
...         pass
...
>>> x = X()
>>> getargspec(x.foo2).args
['self', 'a', 'b']
```

and also:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo3(a, b, c):
...     pass
...
>>> foo4 = partial(foo3, c=1)
>>> getargspec(foo4).args
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <functools.partial object at 0x000000000262F598> is not a Python function
```

How can I make `foo1`, `x.foo2` and `foo4` all return `['a', 'b']`?

Comment: Why are those return values unexpected for you?

Comment: @VincentSavard: because `x.foo2` should be called as `x.foo2(a, b)`

Comment: @eph: so? That doesn't mean that the `self` argument doesn't exist, only that it'll be passed in for you.

Comment: @eph: But you have to remember that `x.foo2(a, b)` is syntactic sugar for `X.foo2(x, a, b)`. `x.foo2` just refers to the function object, but it does not inject `x` into the arguments (because partially applying arguments isn't possible natively in Python).

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution, or something that will parse a limited set of situations? Because I'm pretty sure a generic solution does not exist (and my frail memory supplies something sounding like "NP-complete").

Comment: @VincentSavard: Well, I want to get the parameter names of callable objects in the way they are called. So there is no way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`partial()` objects are not functions. Their default arguments are stored as separate attributes, as well as the original callable. Introspect *those*:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo3(a, b, c):
...     pass
...
>>> foo4 = partial(foo3, c=1)
>>> foo4.args, foo4.keywords
((), {'c': 1})
>>> from inspect import getargspec
>>> getargspec(foo4.func)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Methods are thin wrappers around functions passing in the instance as a first argument. The actual function *doesn't change signature*, the only thing that changes is that the first argument is passed in automatically for you.

To build a 'generic' solution, you'll have to test the type of the object you have, to unwrap the method or the partial and special-case those situations:

```
def generic_get_args(callable):
    if {'args', 'keywords', 'func'}.issubset(dir(callable)):
        # assume a partial object
        spec = getargspec(callable.func).args[len(callable.args):]
        return [var for var in spec if var not in callable.keywords]
    if getattr(callable, '__self__', None) is not None:
        # bound method
        return getargspec(callable).args[1:]
    return getargspec(callable).args
```

Demo against your `foo1`, `X().foo2` and `foo4`:

```
>>> generic_get_args(foo1)
['a', 'b']
>>> generic_get_args(X().foo2)
['a', 'b']
>>> generic_get_args(foo4)
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: `generic_get_args` is likely what I wanted. But it should be recursive to handle `partial(partial(foo3, c=1), 1)`...

Answer (score 1):

x.foo2 is a class member, so it has self (class instance) as first argument (just as you have specified).

By the way, you can declare free function in a class which does not have 'self':

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def foo2(a, b):
...         pass
... 
>>> getargspec(X.foo2).args
['a', 'b']
```

foo4 is not a function in the Python sense, it's a class with a specific behaviour, and not the standard Python function.